# How to insert symbols on Notepad++ before a point?

Tags: notepad++

Anyone have an idea about how to insert symbols on Notepad++ every X phrases (point-separated) and also before every linebreak? I am working with plain text.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give some examples of input and output for what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Using the find replace feature in Notepad++.  For the line break you will need to use the **Extended mode** to look for \n and or others.  Make a copy of the file and do a dry run to make sure your getting what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions. As an example, to insert the symbol '#' after every period, you could find `([^.]*)\.` and replace with `\1.#`. The part `[^.]*` matches any number of non-period characters. The parentheses tag this matched sequence as `\1` for reference in the 'replace with' field. The last two symbols in the regular expression simply match a period.

Obviously, this is a needlessly complicated alternative to simply replacing `.` with `.#` in normal search mode, but the advantage is in its flexibility. If you only want to append the #-symbol every third time, you can replace the following regular expression with `\1.#` instead:

```
([^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*)\.
```

As for matching line breaks, just make sure extended search mode is enabled. Different operating systems use different conventions for representing newlines (i.e. 'carriage return', 'line feed' or both). Notepad++ will match these with `\n` or `\r`. E.g., to insert another '#' at the end of each line in a Windows style text file, replace `\r\n` with `#\r\n`.